# ios - sorted fetched property in CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

How to use fetched property to create sorted array? I am new to predicate programming.

Say there are two entities: 'MyEntity' and 'Image'. 'MyEntity' have a to-many relationship to 'Image' called 'images'.
'Image' have two attributes: 'image' and 'index' where I want to use 'index' as sort key to sort images.

I want to have a fetched property 'sortedImages' on 'MyEntity' which will return a sorted version of 'images'.

What I used to do is load all of the images and sort them in memory and store the result but I found this may consume too much memory.

```
- (NSArray *)sortedImages {
    if (!sortedImages) {
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"index" ascending:YES];
        sortedImages = [self.images sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
        [sortedImages retain];
    }
    return sortedImages;
}
```

Comment: Is the image property the actual image data? If so, what you might want to do is store the filepath rather than the actual data. if you do that then you shouldn't run into any issues with memory and you can let you view load the image using the filepath that you have stored.

Comment: @sosborn Yes. The images are loaded from internet and they are small but many. I will consider your solution but I still want to know how to use fetched property because I have many other sorted entities that may needed to change as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if a fetchedProperty is the right solution here, but you can create an NSFetchRequest on the managedObjectContext of the parent entity and use an NSSortDescriptor on the key, "index". That should return a "fault-capable" sorted array of image objects.